# Tell compiler about a local it doesn't know about?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have a function called `let`, which modifies the calling namespace to insert a new variable.

```
def let(**nameValuePair):
    from inspect import stack

    name, value = nameValuePair.items()[0]
    stack()[1][0].f_locals[name] = value
    return value
```

The idea is it allows you insert assignment statements anywhere you want, even where assignment statements aren't typically allowed in Python (albeit, it requires 5 extra characters for `let()`.

This works perfectly when called from the global namespace.

```
>>> let(outside = 'World')
>>> print(outside)
World
```

This fails with the error `NameError: global name 'hello' is not defined`:

```
>>> def breaker():
...     let(hello = 'World')
...     print(hello)
...
>>> breaker()
```

You might jump to the conclusion that the issue is with my `let` function. It is not - my function performs perfectly. To show you that:

```
>>> def fine():
...     let(another = 'World')
...     print(locals()['another'])
...
>>> fine()
World
```

The issue actually comes from when the Python interpreter compiles `breaker`. To demonstrate, I'll create another function which does the same thing as `breaker`, but using an ordinary assignment instead of `let`, and then I'll decompile both with `dis`.

```
>>> def normal():
...     hello = 'World'
...     print(hello)
...
>>> normal()
World

>>> from dis import dis
>>> print(dis(normal))
 0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('World')
 3 STORE_FAST               0 (hello)
 6 LOAD_FAST                0 (hello)
 9 PRINT_ITEM
10 PRINT_NEWLINE
11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
14 RETURN_VALUE

>>> print(dis(breaker))
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (let)
 3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
 6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('World')
 9 CALL_FUNCTION          256
12 POP_TOP
13 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (hello)  # <= This is the real problem.
16 PRINT_ITEM
17 PRINT_NEWLINE
18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
19 RETURN_VALUE
```

The problem is, the compiler is looking over `breaker`, doesn't see that `hello` gets assigned anywhere in the local scope, and so assumes that it must be a global variable.

What can I do about this? When my function gets called, could I, for example, swap out the problematic line that I indicated and replace it with:

```
LOAD_GLOBAL 1 (locals)
CALL_FUNCTION 0
LOAD_CONST 1 ('hello')  # Or whatever the name of the variable is
BINARY_SUBSCR
```

I know that I could quickly fix the immediate problem by simply storing the variable in the global scope, but that could lead to lots of subtle bugs. To name a few:

1. Global variables get written over.
2. Objects might persist in memory for far longer than intended.
3. Something that would be a typo otherwise, is instead valid. (admittedly this one seems quite unlikely).

... Actually, if I can change the compiled code, I could even add a `STORE_GLOBAL` or `DELETE_GLOBAL` after `RETURN_VALUE`, perhaps? Cache the former global variable elsewhere or something?

Comment: Does `let()` have any practical use?  That is, does it do something that an ordinary assignment can't?

Comment: Unless you tell us a little more about the problem `let()` is supposed to solve, the best answer we can give you is "You can't do that."

Comment: @wallyk - In the actual version, `let` also returns `valu`e. This allows you to write code like `if let(count = len(whatever)) > 2:` and now you have access to the variable `count`. Without it, you'd either need to define `count` separately, or you'd need to call `len()` multiple times in this scenario. Even more useful in `while` loops, where without it, you frequently need to write your assignment both before and at the end of your loop, or you make your loop condition`True`, then assign the variable, then check it in an `if`, then `break` if it isn't met.

Comment: If you showed that in the code above, others could experiment.

Comment: @wallyk - It's not relevant to the problem, so I chose to exclude it from the example. Anyways, it's a single line - I added it in. The function is already published on pip (`pip install let`) - I just realized the other day that I had only tested it in a global namespace, or namespaces where a local variable was simply being overwritten. It fails if there isn't a local variable with that name and it called from the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `locals()` notes the following:

> **Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes
>   may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

I checked and don't see an explicit note in the `inspect` docs about `f_locals` but I don't see why it would be any different.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is, you can't do that. You can't do it in 3.x, you couldn't do it in recent versions of 2.x, and I'd be surprised if you could ever reliably do it. You won't be able to do it in the future, either, because local variables are too easy a target for optimization. There's no way one compiler would go for that, much less all the python compilers.

On the other hand, maybe there's another way to do what you're trying to do. What is that?

Comment: I've elaborated on what I'm trying to do in a comment on the question.

Comment: So, no. You're probably better off checking the locals() to see if there's a symbol of that name listed, and raising an exception if so. (Something like, "Can only use 'let' on non-local variables".) Otherwise, you'll get out of sync quickly due to standard optimizations.